# Como saber se uma classe implementa uma interface?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface

Em PHP, podemos implementar uma (ou mais) `interface` numa classe.

Assim:

```
  interface Authenticable {
       // métodos
  }

  interface Model {
      // métodos
  }

  class Person implements Authenticable, Model {
     // métodos
  }
```

No exemplo acima, `Person` implementa `Authenticable` e `Model`.

Como eu poderia fazer uma verificação pra saber se determinada classe implementa uma interface? Por exemplo, como saber que uma determinada instância de `Person` implementa `Authenticable`?

<sub>**Nota**: Costumo utilizar sempre versões do PHP 5.4 >=. Então seria preferível uma forma mais atual possível para tal operação.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usa-se o operador [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php):

```
interface Authenticable {
     // métodos
}
interface Model {
    // métodos
}
class Person implements Authenticable, Model {
   // métodos
}
$pessoa = new Person();
if ($pessoa instanceof Model) echo "implementa Model";
if ($pessoa instanceof Cloneable) echo "implementa Cloneable";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/trlr3x). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vtdgdijb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/InstanceOf.php).

Não é o que deseja e em poucas situações é útil (acho que só se estiver fazendo alguma ferramenta auxiliar), mas se preferir [pode listar tudo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php):

```
interface Authenticable {
     // métodos
}
interface Model {
    // métodos
}
class Person implements Authenticable, Model {
   // métodos
}
$pessoa = new Person();
print_r(class_implements($pessoa));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vBQHXH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bsswuusp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/InstanceOf2.php).

Comment: Certinho, é isso mesmo +1. Agora fico me  questionando se `instanceof` foi uma abordagem correta do PHP para detectar interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Para saber quais interfaces uma classe implementa, basta usar a função [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) [class_implements()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php)

Escopo

```
array class_implements ( mixed $class [, bool $autoload = true ] )
```

A partir do PHP 5.1 pode definir o nome da classe como string:

```
$rs = class_implements('Foo');
var_dump($rs);
```

Podemos usar [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) como um meio mais prático, porém é preciso ter certeza de que a instância é uma interface, caso contrário, poderá criar uma inconsistência retornando class extendidas ao invés de interfaces.
Além do mais, com `instanceof` assume-se que você já sabe o nome das interfaces. Com `class_implements()` é retornado um array de nomes dos objetos implementados. É mais útil para quando não sabe quais objetos são implementados.

Esses são os objetos que usaremos para testes:

```
interface iFoo {
}

class Bar {
}

class Foo implements ifoo {
}

class Foo2 extends Bar {
}
```

## Teste com class_implements()

```
$rs = class_implements('Foo');
var_dump($rs);
/*
array(1) {
  ["iFoo"]=>
  string(4) "iFoo"
}
*/

$rs = class_implements('Foo2');
var_dump($rs);
/*
Foo2 é uma instância de Bar, porém, não retorna ao invocar class_implements() por ser uma class e não uma interface. O resultado nesse caso é vazio.

array(0) {
}
*/
```

## Teste com instanceof

```
O uso do `instanceof` pode causar inconsistência. Veja o exemplo:

$c = new Foo;
if ($c instanceof iFoo) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
/*
iFoo é uma interface. O retorno é 'yes'.
*/

$c = new Foo2;
if ($c instanceof Bar) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}

/*
Bar() não é uma interface, mas ainda assim retorna 'yes' porque instanceof não distingue se o objeto é uma class ou uma interface.
Isso é um exemplo de inconsistência.
*/
```

É bom deixar claro que não quero dizer seja errado usar `instanceof` para tal finalidade (dentro do contexto da pergunta), desde que observadas as ressalvas.

Entretanto, é bom ressaltar sobre a inconsistência quando indicar o uso de `instanceof` para tal finalidade. Por segurança, utilize o que for mais consistente, a função `class_implements()`.

## Reflection?

Eu prefereria nem comentar uso do `Reflection` pois, para tarefas estáticas não tem sentido o uso de classes OOP.

Mas caso já possua uma instância do [ReflectionClass()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php), poderá aproveitá-la para obter uma lista das interfaces que o objeto implementa:

```
$rs = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
var_dump($rs->getInterfaces());
/*
array(1) {
  ["iFoo"]=>
  object(ReflectionClass)#2 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "iFoo"
  }
}
*/
```

Referência: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getinterfaces.php

Obs: Nos exemplos acima mostram apenas como abstrair os dados. Não preciso mostrar como usar `if else`, `in_array()` e coisas do tipo, para pegar o nome de um objeto que pode estar presente no resultado. Afinal, quem está lendo isso já deve saber usar coisas tão básicas.