# Uma subclass ou classe filha herda também a interface de sua clase mãe?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Seguindo o pilar de encapsulamento proposto em POO me surgiu a seguinte dúvida, quando é declarada uma classe filha, além de herda atributos e métodos ela também herda a interface de sua mãe?

```
interface ContaUsuario {
    public carregue($id,$nome);
}
class conta implements ContaUsuario {
   protected $id;
   private $nome;

   public carregue($id,$nome){
      $this->id = $id;
      $this->nome = $nome;

   }
}
```

Quando eu declaras a class aluno além dela herda esse 2 atributos e 1 função ela herda também a interface ou eu teria que recriá-la ?

Comment: ela herda a interface...

Comment: Uma classe conta que implementa ContaUsuario ... !!! esse seria o correto.

Comment: Não entendi @VirgilioNovic.

Comment: Você nunca vai herdar uma `interface`, elas são implementadas ... Herança acontece de classes `Abstract` (quem também podem ter métodos que são implementados) e `Concretas`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você define a interface em uma classe pai, a classe filha também sofrerá o mesmo efeito. Isto é, se a classe `Conta` implementa a interface `ContaUsuario`, a classe `Aluno`, que herda `Conta`, também implementará a interface. Veja um teste bem simples:

```
interface ContaUsuario {
    public function carregue($id, $nome);
}

class Conta implements ContaUsuario {
   protected $id;
   private $nome;

   public function carregue($id,$nome){
      $this->id = $id;
      $this->nome = $nome;

   }
}

class Aluno extends Conta {}

$aluno = new Aluno();

echo "Instância de Aluno: " . (($aluno instanceof Aluno) ? "Sim" : "Não"), PHP_EOL;
echo "Instância de Conta: " . (($aluno instanceof Conta) ? "Sim" : "Não"), PHP_EOL;
echo "Instância de ContaUsuario: " . (($aluno instanceof ContaUsuario) ? "Sim" : "Não"), PHP_EOL;
```

A saída do código é:

```
Instância de Aluno: Sim
Instância de Conta: Sim
Instância de ContaUsuario: Sim
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/w6J33R).

**Perguntas relacionadas:**

[Como saber se uma classe implementa uma interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160384/5878)

[Como e quando usar Interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/5878)

[Quando usar Interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62885/5878)

[Classe Abstrata X Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/5878)

[Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/5878)